# pivot table: how to prepare the data model where located in different columns

Tags: pivot-table

Sorry I really don't know what is the best title for this question.
I have a mass data, look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPuP9.png).
And the final output should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccDmX.png).
As you can see in the column label (Economic Label), it has
Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing (A)
Commerce, Transportation, Hospitality, Information/Communication
Construction (F)
Finance, Insurance, Utilities, Real Estate/Housing
Manufacturing (C)
Manufacturing Excluding Construction (B-E)
Public and Other Education, Health

But my question is, how this output generated?
Because Agriculture, Construction ... etc, they are in the different columns. If I put it in the columns, it will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6HOo.png). It shows the number, not the title of the record.

I know if I have a table looks like this

```
  |             1            |
--------------------------------
A | economic sector (header) |
B | Agriculture              |
C | Construction             |
D | ...                      |
```

Then I can let all the title of record show properly. But if I do in this way, I cannot get the number.
My [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykwJ3.png) looks blank, something like this image.

**My question is, if there are different title of record in different columns. For example, Agriculture, Construction, Manufacturing ... etc. How can I use this data and put it into pivot table's column and still get the correct number?**

Comment: Hi, please could you add a list of the columns you have in the data source for the pivot table shown in the final link in your post?

Comment: @FlexYourData Sorry, I am not a native English speaker, so I don't know what you mean. You mean the name of different industries? Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing (A)
Commerce, Transportation, Hospitality, Information/Communication
Construction (F)
Finance, Insurance, Utilities, Real Estate/Housing
Manufacturing (C)
Manufacturing Excluding Construction (B-E)
Public and Other Education, Health

Comment: the final link's pivot table fields: https://imgur.com/a/K88B2Ev

Comment: No problem. Please edit your post. Add a list of column names in the table that is the data source for this pivot table https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykwJ3.png

Comment: OK, give me a moment. I will write an answer.

Comment: @FlexYourData thank you so much, I have been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you start with something like this:

[image]

You place your cursor in the table and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range. You'll see this in the Power Query Editor:

[image]

Select the sector columns, then use Tranform>Unpivot columns.

It will look like this:

[image]

Now use Home>Close & Load to put the query back on the spreadsheet.

Create a pivot table from this new data table.

[image]

I hope this will be enough to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps me a lot! Now I think I know how to do it. Very appreciate!